# Having an image within a background always on the same position?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I think I have an impossible task  but before giving up on this I want to be sure that it's really not possible. Maybe it's possible with millions of media queries, but that isn't worth the struggle.

However, I have a backgroundimage with a height of 100vh, meaning it's always 100% height of the users window, and a width of 100%. These two things might make my task impossible.

Within the background image I have another image which should always be on that position, no matter what.

I came up with an example. I want the rocket always stay on that rectangle on the planet. I made this possible on my screen, but it could slip on your screen due different screen sizes.

[image: Should always look like this]

[image: When screen size changes]

(stackoverflow doesn't allow images with http, so please change the image src to http or take a look at my codepen: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjXbPL`)

```css
.background {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://wallpaper-house.com/data/out/7/wallpaper2you_191762.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 240px;
  right: 780px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <img src="https://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-7647188dd0df401f7ec5c5358a0af9a1-rocket.png">
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I deleted my answer because upon testing it would be too hard to maintain... your best option would be to photoshop it into the picture itself

Comment: unfortunately I can't photoshop it in the image itself because I want to create an animation on it

Comment: You can use a graphical tool to create an animation by using the file format SVG which allows you to manipulate vectors within the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Use Position fixed as u do.
Use Left and top, not right.
Put the image beside the background div not in it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the image as background, I've used an inline image with the rocket placed on top. Then the rocket and background are made responsive relative to each other.

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
}
.background img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#rocket {
  top: 49%;
  left: 47%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-image: url(http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-7647188dd0df401f7ec5c5358a0af9a1-rocket.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <img src="https://wallpaper-house.com/data/out/7/wallpaper2you_191762.jpg">
  <div id="rocket"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attached codesnippet shows you a solution. It is based on that you put your rocket and background in 2 different divs and stack them by using CSS-index.
Further on, the rocket is positioned fixed and I added a height of the background that makes it a bit scrollable.

Now, to solve the graphical split of the rocket and the background image you would have to create them as 2 different images and place them into each respective div in the HTML (see codesnippet).

In terms of using different devices you would have to test how the rocket might change position and solve that through a combination of media queries, and potentially use % position instead of px (to position the rocket correct):

```css
.background-pic {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.rocket {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pic"></div>
<div class="rocket"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this can be really hard to achieve is because you're using `background-size: cover;` which means stretch the image while keeping its aspect ratio and crop the image in order to fit its container's height and width. When you combine this with `background-position: center center;` it will crop on the edges equally. Then finally you're using two different kinds of measurement units:  `height: 100vh; width: 100%;`

The question then becomes, before the image is cropped, what's the new width and height for the image that "cover" is applying?

This is something very difficult for CSS to determine because it requires things like knowing the ratio of your image (2560x1600 has a ratio of 1.6:1), then trying to fit it inside a container of variable width and height such that it is just small enough to fill it, while cropping out anything left out, before it is cropped, what is the actual size of the image?

Both `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100%;` will affect its size, in the manner explained above. As this requires comparing the image's original height and width, with the container's width and height to determine how to stretch the image, trying to figure this sort of math out with pure CSS isn't an easy feat for CSS to achieve without some assistance from JavaScript.

A decent solution is to add a bunch of transparency to the rocket image so it has the same size as the background so it can also go through the same "cover" stretching and cropping logic.

Give this a shot:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjrPvM

HTML:

```
<div class="background" data-comment="2560x1600 has an aspect ratio of 1.6:1"> 
  <div class="rocket">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://wallpaper-house.com/data/out/7/wallpaper2you_191762.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.rocket {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:     
    url('your-rocket-on-a-2560x1600-canvas-with-lots-of-transparency.png');
}
```

Within the codepen I used a base64 encoded version of "your-rocket-on-a-2560x1600-canvas-with-lots-of-transparency.png"
which is just the rocket placed on a 2560x1600 canvas I did in GIMP, transformed it -20.0 degrees moved it around so it's placed where you want it then exported it as a PNG.

Answer (score -1):

Up to some point, it's possible. Here is my solution for that, I have tried and tested your code. These are the changes to fix your code:

Set the position of the image to `fixed`:

```
img
{
      width: 150px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: 20px; (adjust some pixels as per your need)
      right: 50%;
      margin-right: -90px;(adjust some pixel as per your need)
      transform: rotate(-20deg)
}
```

Here is the complete working example:
https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/MGooLr